# I need to send some text to a created input in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, input

I generated a table with javascript for add rows when you need (it is an order form) and for the product input I need to take the details from database. In order to do so, I am trying now with a prompt very simple pop-up in javascript, and with a function I catch the id of the input I need to fill (each row and each field has their own id, obviously). I attache the example code that I am trying now, I always have the same problem, I cannot find the input id for put the text on.

This is the function that generates the prompt, i don't changed anything, only for try if i can send the text to my input:

```js
function PopupProd(n) {
    var txt;
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Maria");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
        txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
    } else {
        txt = "Hello " + person + "! How are you today?";
    }
    //here is my problem, I tried with innerHTML too, and in many ways for find the id input
    document.getElementById('n').value = txt;
}
```

And this is the field where I generate the button for show the prompt, in the same row than "n" input:

```
if (c == 2) {
    var popeleProd = document.createElement('input');
    // set the attributes.
    popeleProd.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    popeleProd.setAttribute('value', 'Producto');
    // add button's "onclick" event.
    //numline is the variable that contains the number of row that I am looking for
    //it works
    popeleProd.setAttribute('onclick', 'PopupProd(idProd' + numline + ')');

    td.appendChild(popeleProd);
}
```

I am quite new in javascript, and I think the problem is because I generate the table, and the javascript cannot find where have to put the text, can you help me please? I don`t now if you need more code for understand. I have to say that I tried so many ways to do, and I always have the same problem, I can see that I find the id, but i cannot send the text to it.

Thank you!!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]

Comment: you question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, I deleted the question, and I thought that would be not visible for anyone. Thanks!!